# How can I update the creation and/or the last modified time of a file stored on OneDrive (Business) using the OneDrive SDK

Tags: c#, onedrive

I'm trying to update the creation and last modified date of a file stored on OneDrive (Business).

I've successfully updated/set other file attributes (or facets), but, for some reason, when I try to update the date/time facets my code always throws the following exception

```
'Microsoft.OneDrive.Sdk.OneDriveException' with Error = {Code: invalidRequest Message: The request is malformed or incorrect.}
```

The code is relatively straight forward (taken from a SDK sample)

```
var remoteFileId = "0153C2VFI2EGGLRJXTANFLXLWP6UJXCFW3";
var newItemFacets = new Item
{
    FileSystemInfo = new FileSystemInfo
    {
        CreatedDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now - TimeSpan.FromDays(1),
        LastModifiedDateTime = DateTimeOffset.Now
    }
};

await _oneDriveClient
    .Drive
    .Items[remoteFileId]
    .Request()
    .UpdateAsync(newItemFacets);
```

The value of remoteFileId is of course specific to a file stored on my OneDrive.

Does anyone have any idea as to why this code might be failing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably because of this:

> **Remarks**
>
> The **FileSystemInfo** property is not available for items in SharePoint
>   or OneDrive for Business.

https://dev.onedrive.com/facets/filesysteminfo_facet.htm